# Saving the data object in an array from angular to nodejs mongoose

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, model, mongoose-schema

I have a form in Angular and it is successfully connected to Node JS because some datas in my form are save in mongoDB. But I have a problem with some of the datas specifically `measurementUsed` and `testTolerance` because it is not saved in my mongoDB.

This is my model structure

`equipment.model.js`

```
const equipSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  // ..
     other property names
     .. 

  measurementPerformed: [{
    measurementUsed: String,
    testTolerance: String
  }],

  // ..
     other property names
     .. 
});

module.exports = restful.model('Equipment', equipSchema);
```

`equipment.js`

```js
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body.instrumentName) {
        res.status(401)
        .send({message: 'No equipment registered!'});
    }   else {
        const newEquipment = {
            instrumentName: req.body.instrumentName,
            manufacturer: req.body.manufacturer,
            model: req.body.model
            measurementUsed: req.body.measurementPerformed.measurementUsed,
            testTolerance: req.body.measurementPerformed.testTolerance,
            testMethod: req.body.testMethod
        }
        new Equipment(newEquipment)
            .save()
            .then(equipment => res.json(equipment))
            .catch(() => {
                res.status(500)
                .send({message: 'registration of equipment failed.'})
            })
    } });
```

`equipment.component.html`

```html
 <div class="intella-form-group" formArrayName="measurementPerformed">
         <ul class="intella-form-fields" *ngFor="let measurement of instrumentData.controls.measurementPerformed.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
             <h4>#{{ i+1 }}</h4>
               <li>
                 <input type="text" formControlName="measurementUsed">
                 <input type="text" formControlName="testTolerance">
               </li>
             </ul>
           </div>
```

`equipment.ts`

```
export class InstrumentRegistrationFormComponent implements OnInit {
  instrumentData: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private equipmentService: EquipmentService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.instrumentData = this.formBuilder.group({
      'instrumentName': '',
      'manufacturer': '',
      'model': '',
      'serialNumber': '',
      'location': '',
      'particulars': this.formBuilder.array([]),
      'mainVoltage': '',
      'deviceCurrent': '',
      'earthResistance': '',
      'groundCurrent': '',
      'temperature': '',
      'humidity': '',
      'measurementPerformed': this.formBuilder.array([ this.verifyCalibration() ]),
      'testMethod': ''
    });
  }

  verifyCalibration() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      'measurementUsed': [''],
      'testTolerance': ['']
    });
  }

  addMeasurement() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.instrumentData.controls['measurementPerformed'];
    control.push(this.verifyCalibration());
  }

  removeOneMeasurement(i: number) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.instrumentData.controls['measurementPerformed'];
    control.removeAt(i);
  }

  setStandard() {
    this.dialog.open(SettingStandardComponent);
  }

  saveInstruments() {
    this.equipmentService.addInstrument(this.instrumentData.value)
      .subscribe(
        response => console.log(response),
        error => console.log(error)
      );
    // console.log(this.instrumentData.value);
    this.instrumentData.reset();
  }

}
```

#### problem

> **measurementUsed**: req.body.measurementPerformed.measurementUsed,
>   **testTolerance**: req.body.measurementPerformed.testTolerance

#### result

```
 "measurementPerformed": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5ab214d22e7e571b840fa82b"
            }
        }
    ],
```

It doesn't save the `measurmentUsed` and the `testTolerance` in my mongoDB.

Comment: It would be nice to have your Angular code.

Comment: ok, sorry. will add my angular code. Well actually, in Angular alone outputting the data through `console.log`, everything is valid and correct.

Comment: Doesn't mean you send the payload well.

Comment: i added my angular code.

Answer (score 1):

It's not saving because your schema is different than your variable  "newEquipment". Use:

```
const newObject = {
    measurementUsed: req.body.measurementPerformed.measurementUsed,
    testTolerance: req.body.measurementPerformed.testTolerance
  }
const newEquipment = {
    ... //remove measurementUsed and testTolerance assignment
    measurementPerformed.push(newObject);
    ...
}
```

in defining newEquipment object.

Comment: it results unexpected token if I do that

Comment: Refactor you schema. Keep both variables out of measurementPerformed array. It should work, with your original code.
If you don't want to refactor, then just remove the array brackets []. Then it won't throw unexpected token error for measurementPerformed.measurementUsed

Comment: I tried to refactor my schema model. but with only example `measurementPerformed[0].measurementUsed` it will only save the 1st data, but not the incremented data

Comment: router.post will create a new object for every submit. If you want to update existing object in database, you have to write new router and functions for that. I have updated the code for inserting new values.